# Seemingly "garbage" result with requests

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I have [this](https://www.worldmarktheclub.com/resorts/7m/) webpage. When I try to get its html using `requests` module like this :

```
import requests

link = "https://www.worldmarktheclub.com/resorts/7m/"
f = requests.get(link)
print(f.text)
```

I get a result like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
<meta http-equiv="CacheControl" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo="/>

<script>

(function(){
    var securemsg;
    var dosl7_common;

// seemingly garbage like [Z.li]+Z._j+Z.LO+Z.SJ+"(/.{"+Z.i+","+Z.Ii+"}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/TSPD/08e841a5c5ab20007f02433a700e2faba779c2e847ad5d441605ef3d4bbde75cd229bcdb30078f66?type=9"></script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>
</head><body>
</body></html>
```

Only a part of the result shown. But I can see the proper html when I inspect the webpage in a browser. I guess there might be an issue with the encoding of the page, but can't figure it out. Using `urllib.request` + `read()` gives the same wrong result. How do I correct this. Thanks in advance.

As suggested by @DeepSpace, the garbage issue in script is due to the minified JS code. But why am I not getting the html correctly?

Comment: If I understand well, you want to see the HTML content of the requested page ?

Comment: @LouisSaglio, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you deem as "garbage" is obfuscated/minified JS code that is written in `<script>` tags instead of in an external JS file.

If you look at the bottom of `f.text`, you will see `<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>`.

`requests` is not a browser, hence it can not execute JS code which this page is making use of, and the server will not allow user-agents who do not support JS to access it. Setting the `User-Agent` header to Chrome's (`Chrome/60.0.3112.90`) still does not work.

You will have to resort to other tools that allow JS execution, such as selenium.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But if it is not enclosed in ``<script>`` tags like the body of the page which is pure html, return ``<body>\r\n</body>``

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code is produced on the fly by the Javascript code you see. Unfortunately, as said by @DeepSpace, requests does not execute Javascript.

As an alternative I suggest to use selenium. It is a library which simulate a browser and so execute Javascript.